# How to create serviceaccount with access to two namespaces Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have question about create one serviceaccount with access to two namespaces. I tried create roles and rolebinding but It doesn't work. Because I want to create readonly access to developer to microservices. I don't know it should be cluster role or role. And developer should have access to readonly for pods and services.

Thank you!

I tried create Roles with mixed namespaces